# aysnchronous calls not evaluating condition in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

I have an authenticator file which based on the state renders different components. The problem is that the following code does not work. I need to make the code wait until the component checks the condition if condition. 
So basically it should wait for this condition to evaluate

```
isSignedIn() === true
```

And based on this condition take the respective decision.
Any help is appreciated.

```js
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth'

export default class Authenticator extends Component {
  isSignedIn = async () => {
    let isUserAuthenticated
    try {
      const userSession = await Auth.currentSession()
      if(userSession.idToken != null) {
        isUserAuthenticated = true
      } 
    }
    catch (error) {
      isUserAuthenticated = false
    }
    return isUserAuthenticated
  }

  render() {
    if(isSignedIn() === true) {
      return null
    }
    else {
      return <SignIn/>
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that it starts to render sign in page though i have used the async function.

Comment: Have you tried using a promise?

Comment: No, can you post it as an answer that how it could be accommodated here

Comment: @TomaszRup Yes he does, he's using `async`/`await`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `async` function will always return a promise, so you cannot use what it returns in a synchronous way.

You could instead check if the user is authenticated in `componentDidMount` and put the result in the component's state and use that for rendering.

**Example**

```
import Auth from "@aws-amplify/auth";

export default class Authenticator extends Component {
  state = {
    signedIn: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkUserStatus();
  }

  checkUserStatus = async () => {
    try {
      const userSession = await Auth.currentSession();
      if (userSession.idToken != null) {
        this.setState({ signedIn: true });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ signedIn: false });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { signedIn } = this.state;

    if (signedIn === null || signedIn) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return <SignIn />;
    }
  }
}
```